# Join with constraint on dates

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two dataframes, as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : [A, B, A, A, C],
 'date' : [01-01-15, 31-01-15, 03-02-15, 03-02-15, 15-03-16],
 'attr':[1, 5, 3, 5, 6]
  }, columns=['Id','date', 'attr'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : [A, B, A, A, B],
 'date' : [01-02-15, 01-01-15, 02-02-15, 03-12-15, 15-03-16],
 'counter':[1, 1, 2, 3, 2]
  }, columns=['Id','date', 'counter'])
```

The first one contains an Id, a date and some attributes.
The second one contains an Id, a date and other attributes (counters increasing as the time passes).
Note that all attributes appear multiple times.

Now, I want to "join" the two based on the Id, but considering only the closest date in the past for df2.

In practice, my expected output would be:

```
Id | date     | att | counter
A  | 01-01-15 | 1   | Nan
B  | 31-01-15 | 5   | 1 
A  | 03-02-15 | 3   | 2
A  | 03-02-15 | 5   | 2
C  | 15-03-16 | 6   | NaN
```

Note that the NaN could be replaced by any other reasonable value, 0 included.

The first df contains about 300K rows, while the second one about 3 millions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible since you need an exact value to join. The best I can think of is you truncate your dates to months only, then write some custom function to join based on what days have counters inside that grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**`pd.merge_asof`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.sort_values('date'), on='date', by='Id')

  Id       date  attr  counter
0  A 2015-01-01     1      NaN
1  B 2015-01-31     5      1.0
2  A 2015-03-02     3      2.0
3  A 2015-03-02     5      2.0
4  C 2016-03-15     6      NaN
```

---

The default value for the `direction` argument is `'backward'`
From Docs

> Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.
>
> For each row in the left DataFrame:
>
> - A “backward” search selects the last row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s key.
> - A “forward” search selects the first row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is greater than or equal to the left’s key.
> - A “nearest” search selects the row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is closest in absolute distance to the left’s key.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I get the following error.
_TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable_.
I'm trying to debug it but I'm not having much luck.
None of Id or Date is NULL or NaN.

Comment: Does what I've provided work when you run it on the toy data?  If so, then it is your data.  If it doesn't work on the toy data then it is versioning.  I'm running Python 3.6 and pandas 0.22.  If it works on toy data, then you should provide enough data such that the error occurs but keep it minimal.

Comment: It works. I was not using datetime64[ns]. Thanks a lot!